# Google Cloud Functions deploy failed: build/src/index.js does not exist

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I followed this document https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/master/docs/typescript.md to implement a Google Cloud Funtion (NOT Firebase) in TypeScript, and I met an error which says *build/src/index.js does not exist* when deployment. But I checked both my local project and source zip package from Cloud Functions with `tsc` command, both are able to compile successfully and generate build/src/index.js file. Did anybody face the same problem? Any help would be very appreciated!

After `rm -rf build;yarn compile&&ll build/src`, as you can see, build/src/index.js is here, but I don't know why it keeps saying that error message.

```bash
yarn run v1.22.19
$ tsc
✨  Done in 1.66s.
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 capt.michael  staff   160B Oct 19 21:03 base
drwxr-xr-x  5 capt.michael  staff   160B Oct 19 21:03 handlers
-rw-r--r--  1 capt.michael  staff   146B Oct 19 21:03 index.d.ts
-rw-r--r--  1 capt.michael  staff   1.5K Oct 19 21:03 index.js
-rw-r--r--  1 capt.michael  staff   1.1K Oct 19 21:03 index.js.map
drwxr-xr-x  5 capt.michael  staff   160B Oct 19 21:03 types
```

[image: Logs on Google Cloud Funtions console]

Comment: If you don't get any responses, I'd suggest describing each of the steps ... from scratch ... that you performed allowing others to attempt to recreate what you are finding.

Comment: If you are still facing issue, please share the steps asked by kolban in the above comment?